# Loopback enabled UWP app successfully reach localhost service only when Fiddler is running

Tags: loopback, uwp

For develop purpose only I'm testing a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) client app locally on my Windows 10 Laptop, where a WebAPI service is running.

By default, WinRT apps cannot connect to localhost but Visual Studio locally deployed apps should, but I coudn't manage to succeed.

Then I've used Fiddler to check and eventually enable loopback ability for my UWP app and found that it was already enabled.

By accident I've discovered that only while Fiddler is running, my UWP app can connect to the WebAPI service.

I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiddler is able to Allow your App to use the local network loopback.

[image: Fiddler]

Simply check your App and you can reach your WebService.
You will see if you uncheck your App, you won't reach your WebService again.

Visual Studio enables the local network loopback while debugging as well if you check the option in your Projects Debugging Properties. (Project -> Properties -> Debugging -> Allow local network loopback)

Comment: I knew about Fiddler but I was missing the Visual Studio setting. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this works for client sockets only, if your UWP app has a server (listening) Socket or StreamSocket you're out of luck